# bash order of commands?

Tags: linux, bash, cat, ls

after wondering how if can pipe ls into cat to output a bunch of files I realized a better way to do that is to `cat $ $(ls *.py)`, but also realized that `$(ls *.py) cat $`  does not work:

```
$(ls *.py) cat $                                                   1 ⨯
bash: command not found: 1.py
```

to me this is weird, why does this happen?

Comment: You have a $() and inside that context ls is being executed. So the returned content will be executed. As it returned 1.py etc it made the execution as $(1.py 2.py). ls displays output, why do you need a cat again? I am confused on the requirement here.

Comment: There are several reasons to avoid parsing the output of `ls` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985). The reason your command is failing is that you forgot the pipe symbol, e.g. `ls *.py | cat` should work, but instead it would be better to use `cat *.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: don't use `$(ls *.py)`, just use `*.py`. Adding the `$(ls)` doesn't do anything useful, but it does add a couple of layers of processing and potential confusion. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) for details, but I'll give a quick summary near the end here.

Second: when you use something like `$(ls *.py)` or `*.py` as part of a command like, the shell will "expand" it before executing the command. With `*.py`, that means replacing it with the names of the files matching `*.py` in the current directory. So if you use `cat *.py`, that'll expand to something like:

```
cat 1.py 2.py file.py otherfile.py
```

...which is what you want. But `*.py cat` expands to something like:

```
1.py 2.py file.py otherfile.py cat
```

...which tries to execute `1.py` as the command name (which doesn't exist as a command, so you get a "command not found" error), with the other filenames and "cat" as arguments.

With `$(ls *.py) cat`, it first goes through expanding `*.py` and running `ls 1.py 2.py file.py otherfile.py`, captures the output of that ("1.py 2.py file.py otherfile.py"), splits it into "words" (which *probably* correctly splits it into filenames... unless any files have spaces or you changed `IFS`) then tries to expand any of those that look like wildcards (just like it did the initial `*.py`), then finally builds a command out of those + `cat`. Just like before, that comes out to:

```
1.py 2.py file.py otherfile.py cat
```

which fails as you saw.